# Removing duplicate rows from table and combining data

Tags: sql

I'm creating a temp table from multiple sources and need to remove duplicate records from it.  For example, my temp table will have data like:

```
RecordID     Color
1            Black
2            Black
2            Blue
```

I'd like to consolidate `RecordID` 2 down to:

```
RecordID     Color
1            Black
2            Black,Blue
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please add the relevant tag to your question (mysql, oracle, sql-server...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql GROUP\_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516545/mysql-group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation. The actual aggregate function depends on your RDBMS.

In MySQL, use `GROUP_CONCAT` (the default separator is the comma):

```
SELECT RecordID, GROUP_CONCAT(Color) AS Color
FROM mytable
GROUP BY RecordID
```

In Oracle, use `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT RecordID, LISTAGG(Color, ',') AS Color
FROM mytable
GROUP BY RecordID
```

In Postgres (>=9.0) or SQL-Server 2017, use `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT RecordID, STRING_AGG(Color, ',') AS Color
FROM mytable
GROUP BY RecordID
```

Answer (score 0):

if its oracle then :

```
select "RecordID",listagg("Color",',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "RecordID","Color" ) 
Color
FROM Table1 group by "RecordID";
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abaab5/5