# How to convert row to column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to dynamically convert rows to columns in MySQL.

Table name is student_det.

```
ID    Roll_No         Q.No
1      21345         100
2      21345         102
3      21345         103
4      21346         100
5      21346         144
6      21567         233
7      21567         455

**Ans should be like** 

    Roll_no Qno1    Qno2    Qno3
    21345   100      102    103
    21346   100      144    null
    21567   233      455    null
  ----------
```

The code I use to convert rows to columns, is the following

```
Select roll_no,Q.No1, Q.No2,Q.No3
From
(
  Select Roll_No, Q.No,
    'Q.No'+
      CAST(row_number() over(partition by Roll_No order by Roll_No) 
     as varchar(10)) ColumnSequence
  from student_det
) as Temp
PIVOT
(
  MIN(Q.No)
  FOR ColumnSequence IN(Q.No1, Q.No2,Q.No3)
) as Piv
```

Comment: Why would need to create such a table result? Its not clear what your intention is for this, so maybe [group concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516545/mysql-group-concat) could help? You added the PHP tag which has nothing to do with this question, if you use this data later on in PHP then you could easily create it through the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have PIVOT function, so in order to rotate data from rows into columns you will have to use a CASE expression along with an aggregate function.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table student_det(ID int,   Roll_No int, QNo int);
 insert into student_det values(1      ,21345,         100);
 insert into student_det values(2     , 21345 ,        102);
 insert into student_det values(3    ,  21345  ,       103);
 insert into student_det values(4   ,   21346   ,      100);
 insert into student_det values(5  ,    21346    ,     144);
 insert into student_det values(6 ,     21567     ,    233);
 insert into student_det values(7,      21567      ,   455);
```

Query:

```
 with cte as 
 (
   Select Roll_No, QNo,
       row_number() over(partition by Roll_No order by Roll_No) ColumnSequence
   from student_det
 )
 select roll_no,
        max(case when columnsequence=1 then QNo end)Qno1,
        max(case when columnsequence=2 then QNo end)Qno2,
        max(case when columnsequence=3 then QNo end)Qno3
 from cte       
 group by roll_no
```

Output:

| roll_no | Qno1 | Qno2 | Qno3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21345 | 100 | 102 | 103 |
| 21346 | 100 | 144 | null |
| 21567 | 233 | 455 | null |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8bd5f16866a31634f1e25d4aef46450b)*