# Getting multiple rows data field 2 based on single value from field 1 in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table from which I want to return data based on a distinct **name** column with correspondent multiple row values from the **options** column table.

**Table data:**

[image: here]

**Looking Output:**

```
Name   Options
-----------------------------------
bread  white, brown 
jam    stawberry, apple, mangoe
```

Any suggestion  or best advice is apprecheated

Comment: Please try `GROUP CONCAT`. It is clearly one of the most asked questions in SO. (Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516545/mysql-group-concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is asked every day without fail, you would simply do

```
select name, group_concat(options separator ', ')
from t
group by menu_id, name
```